# Why are my pyplot subplots only taking up half of the figure?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am creating two subplots, side by side, and for some reason they will only fill the top half of the figure.

```
grid = {'width_ratios':[3,1],'height_ratios':[1,1]}
self.fig, self.axes = plt.subplots(1,2, sharey=True, gridspec_kw=grid)
```

And here is what it looks like once I plot everything:

[image: probs]

See how the bottom half of the image is blank? That is how it appears in the figure window. I want the entire figure of subplots to fill the window and be more square shaped, and I can't see any reason why it shouldn't, as I have written it.

Comment: Looks like you are creating `2x2` `subplots`, and you are only using the upper 2

Comment: @Bart I agree that that is what it looks like, but I dont declare a 2x2 when I create the subplots, I create a 1x2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By declaring `'height_ratios':[1,1]` you are creating two rows of `subplots`; similarly `'height_ratios':[1,1,1]` will give you three rows, et cetera. So simply write `'height_ratios':[1]`, or leave out `height_ratios`, and it is fixed.

<s>It's seems strange to me that this setting overrides the explicit `nrows, ncols` settings in Gridspec, but apparently that is what Matplotlib does.</s>... Well, it doesn't override the `nrows, ncols` setting, but with `'height_ratios':[1,1]` you are still creating space for two rows of `subplots`.